# Postgresql initial configuration: How to access as the postgres user?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, ubuntu-12.10

After installing postgresql, I tried it out, typing createdb mydb, like it's written in the documentation. Then the following error occured:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "xxx" does not exist
```

I studied the documentation, where is said:

> You will need to become the operating system user under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres) to create the first user account

I tried this by accessing psql (in my case with sudo -u postgres psql, using Ubuntu 12.10).
But then what should I do?

Comment: have you created a user for your database ? (not pstgres which is the superuser)

Comment: What happens when you just "su - postgres" to become the postgres user, and then try "createdb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the db is owned by user `postgres` you can do the following

`createdb -U postgres dbname`

since by default postgresql will trust connections from localhost.

Comment: Not working.. Resolving to: createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: hmm I am guessing whatever you used to install the server modified the default config to not trust.  try `sudo su -  postgres` and then run the createdb.  not sure

Answer (score 0):

```
su - postgres
```

and after you have been logged in:

```
createdb mydb
```

Comment: su - postgresql gives me following output: Unknown id:postgresql

Comment: su - postgres is the user.

Comment: @SaschaMayr sorry, my typo, try `su - postgres` (without ql at the end), my answer edited